# определение переменной в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы, variable

Недавно заметил в Python что определять переменную можно другим способом:

```
name: str = "Bob"
```

Так вот чем это определение отличается от такой:

```
name = "Bob"
```

Comment: Явно тип указан :) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0613/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сути ничем:

- Вы можете менять им значения на другие типы (что не рекомендуется):

  ```
  name: str = "Bob"
  name = 10
  ```

  Или даже так:

  ```
  name: str = "Bob"
  name: int = 1 + 1
  ```
- Никакой особой разницы между переменной инициализированной "по-старинке" и "модерново" нет. С ними работают одни и те же питоновские приемы.
- **UPD**

  > Между прочим, `name: int = "wtf"` тоже вполне работает – andreymal 4 часа назад

Единственная разница:

- Хорошо для таких вещей как mypy, pylint etc.
- На уровне дизассемблера (у меня version 3.8):

```
>>> dis("a: int = 10")
  1           0 SETUP_ANNOTATIONS
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (int)
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (__annotations__)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             12 STORE_SUBSCR
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
vs.
```

```
>>> dis("a = 10")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

## Dis Explanation

- `SETUP_ANNOTATIONS` — "настройка аннотаций" т.е. "байткод говорит: тут мы юзаем аннотация"
- `2 LOAD_CONST 0 (10)` — подгружаем константу 10.
- `4 STORE_NAME 0 (a)` — сохраняем в а, то что подгрузили.
- А вот тут самое интересное:
- `6 LOAD_NAME  1 (int)` — загружаем инт
- `8 LOAD_NAME 2 (__annotations__)` — загружаем `__annotations__` это по сути словарь в котором хранятся типы переменных. На пример: `a: str = "";print(__annotations__)` даст на стдауте `{'a': <class 'str'>}`
- `10 LOAD_CONST 1 ('a') #it is clear, ain't it`
- `12 STORE_SUBSCR`:

  > **STORE_SUBSCR**
  > Implements TOS1[TOS] = TOS2
  > ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html))
- ```
  14 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
  16 RETURN_VALUE
  ```

  = `return None # functions return None automatically if you don't use any return in it`

  Эта штука ничего не возвращает т.е. None

Comment: А можете пожалуйста объяснить на уровне дизассемблера?

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin Ага, ща в ответ добавлю, подожди 5сек

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin Есть разбор!

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin Поняли?

Comment: ага, тоесть если указывать вот так : name: str = "Bob", то будет лучше для дизассемблера

Comment: Между прочим, `name: int = "wtf"` тоже вполне работает

Comment: @andreymal, да я заметил, а можете пожалуйста объяснить почему не возникает ошибки ?

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin потому что эти аннотации не влияют абсолютно ни на что, кроме как на содержимое словаря `__annotations__`

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin Да нет, для дизассемблера как раз в некотором роде лучше без аннотации т.к. надо меньше дейстив сделать и => быстрее. А аннотации лучше для всякой вспомогаетльной штуки типа mypy, pylint, того что в pycharm etc.

Comment: питон считается языком с динамическим типом данных. поэтому и нет ошибки.

Comment: @Интик Не "считается", а "является". И не "типом данных" — тип данных это например строка, а "типизацией".

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica вы развернули ответ во всю широту души